# how to run gazebo docker container in Mac

Tags: ros, gazebo, macbook, docker, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although gazebo can be installed on Mac directly, I found it's not very reliable during the use - for example, it spins all the time when I even try to drag a simple object into the model editor. I try to setup the docker on my Mac. But no material about how to get the gzclient running although there is way to get gzserver up and running form the gazebo docker container.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316092/how-to-run-gazebo-docker-container-in-mac/) by [JohnFred](https://answers.ros.org/users/40102/johnfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on 2019-02-19**:
Maybe obvious question, but did you try the official gazebo docker images? https://hub.docker.com/_/gazebo

**Comment by [JohnFred](https://answers.ros.org/users/40102/johnfred/) on 2019-02-19**:
Yes. The gazebo docket container only provides a gzserver. It does not prescribe how to get the gzclient side. Just looking for someone to share the experience because I believe many people use Mac for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did quite some research, including using xquartz server for mac and then get gazebo docker container to xquartz. None works because many of the legacy compatibility issues here and there, including XQartz support to new OpenGL etc. Also in the long run, Mac is moving to METAL then OpenGL... Also have looked into other alternative like Gzweb (web version of Gazebo client). Eventually, I started a typical PC + Ubuntu setup and everything is smooth.

---

Originally posted by [JohnFred](https://answers.ros.org/users/40102/johnfred/) with karma: 36 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2019-02-26**:
The osrf/docker_images repo does host dockerfiles for gzweb you could try. I haven't tested them myself in a while though: https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/086440f267921cf4ff39e90bb8e07c81e243dddc/gazebo/9/ubuntu/bionic/gzweb9/Dockerfile